# Decode the product key for Windows Server 2012 not working

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have this function to decode the DigitalProductId from the registry, the same code is all over the internet but is not returning the expected product key in my Windows Server 2012, i have the product key and this code is supposed to find it for me, but it returns a different key:

```
Shared Function DecodeProductKey(digitalProductId As Byte()) As String

    Const keyStartIndex As Integer = 52
    Const keyEndIndex As Integer = keyStartIndex + 15
    Dim digits As Char() = New Char() {"B"c, "C"c, "D"c, "F"c, "G"c, "H"c,
        "J"c, "K"c, "M"c, "P"c, "Q"c, "R"c,
        "T"c, "V"c, "W"c, "X"c, "Y"c, "2"c,
        "3"c, "4"c, "6"c, "7"c, "8"c, "9"c}
    Const decodeLength As Integer = 29
    Const decodeStringLength As Integer = 15
    Dim decodedChars As Char() = New Char(decodeLength - 1) {}
    Dim hexPid As New ArrayList()
    For i As Integer = keyStartIndex To keyEndIndex
        hexPid.Add(digitalProductId(i))
    Next
    For i As Integer = decodeLength - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If (i + 1) Mod 6 = 0 Then
            decodedChars(i) = "-"c
        Else
            Dim digitMapIndex As Integer = 0
            For j As Integer = decodeStringLength - 1 To 0 Step -1
                Dim byteValue As Integer = (digitMapIndex << 8) Or CByte(hexPid(j))
                hexPid(j) = CByte(byteValue \ 24)
                digitMapIndex = byteValue Mod 24
                decodedChars(i) = digits(digitMapIndex)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Return New String(decodedChars)

End Function
```

Is there a new decode method for the Windows Server 2012? 
Has anyone work with this code in this operating system?

Edit:
I get the DigitalProductId from the Registry. What value is supposed to have the product key?
[Registry values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAGmJ.png)

Comment: Where did you get the underlying algorithm from?

Comment: Also note that the "Product ID" (as seen in "About Windows") is separate from the "Product Key" (from the CD case sticker) - and that the Product Key cannot be derived from the Product ID.

Comment: Where does the `digitalProductId` array come from, that seems as likely to change as the decoder (which is correct)

Comment: How do i get the product Key then? If the digitalProductId doesn't have it.